# R roll mean on a non continuous time serie

Tags: r, time-series, grouping, mean

I want to make a rolling mean on the last X number of days. `rollmean()` does that using rows. Since I am using loggers that sometimes fail, and also the data were cleaned, the time series is not continuous (rows do not necessarily represent a constant time difference).

A colleague suggested the solution below, which works great. Except my data need to be grouped (in the example by treatment). For each day, I want the rolling mean of the last X days for each treatment.

Thanks

```
 # making some example data
 # vector with days since the beginning of experiment

days <- 0:30
 
 # random values df1 <-   tibble::tibble(
     days_since_beginning = days,
     value_to_used = rnorm(length(days)),
     treatment = sample(letters[1],31,replace = TRUE)   )
 
 df2 <-   tibble::tibble(
     days_since_beginning = days,
     value_to_used = rnorm(length(days)),
     treatment = sample(letters[2],31,replace = TRUE)   )
 
 df <- full_join(df1, df2)
 
 # how long should be the period for mean

 time_period <- 10 # calculate for last 10 days
 
 
 df_mean <- df %>%    dplyr::mutate(
     # calculate rolling mean 
     roll_mean = purrr::map_dbl(
       .x = days_since_beginning,
       .f = ~ df %>% 
         # select only data for the last `time_period`
         dplyr::filter(days_since_beginning >= .x - time_period &
                         days_since_beginning <= .x) %>% 
         purrr::pluck("value_to_used") %>% 
         mean() %>% 
         return()
     )   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes the mean over the last 10 days by treatment.  The width argument includes a computation of how many rows back to use so that it corresponds to 10 days rather than 10 rows.  This uses the fact that width can be a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(roll = rollapplyr(value_to_used, 
    seq_along(days_since_beginning) - findInterval(days_since_beginning - 10, days_since_beginning), 
    mean)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks! I replaced `- 10` by `time_period + 1`. It seems that your solution does not include the lower limit of the time period.

Comment: 10 days means that it averages over 10 days if there are no gaps.  If you add 1 then you are averaging over 11 days if there are no gaps.  The current day is included.  For example, `tt <- BOD$Time;
rollapplyr(1:6, seq_along(tt) - findInterval(tt - 3, tt), length)`  uses these number of points 1 2 3 3 3 2.

Answer (score 0):

Same colleague came up with his own solution:

```
df_mean <- 
  df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(treatment) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    data_with_mean = purrr::map(
      .x = data,
      .f = ~ {
        dataset <- .x
        
        dataset %>% 
          dplyr::mutate(
            # calculate rolling mean 
            roll_mean = purrr::map_dbl(
              .x = days_since_beginning,
              .f = ~ dataset %>% 
                # select only data for the last `time_period`
                dplyr::filter(days_since_beginning >= .x - time_period &
                                days_since_beginning <= .x) %>% 
                purrr::pluck("value_to_used") %>% 
                mean() %>% 
                return()
            )) %>% 
          return()
        
      }
    )) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-data) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(data_with_mean) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

I compared the results with G. Grothendieck's idea, and it only matches if I use `time_period` in my colleague's code and `time_period + 1` in G. Grothendieck's code. So there is a difference in how the `time_period` is used, and I am confused about why it happens.